# Parsing table-like string into JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, parsing

This string is structured in a human-readable table-like way. It contains three columns. However, the only information I need is a list of all of the values from the first column.

```
app115                                115.115                              winget
app225                                115.115Chrome                        winget
Knotes                                1MHz.Knotes                          winget
BPMN-RPA Studio                       1ic.BPMN-RPAstudio                   winget
Fishing Funds                         1zilc.FishingFunds                   winget
3601                                  360.360Chrome                        winget
3602                                  360.360Chrome.X                      winget
3603                                  360.360CleanMaster                   winget
3604                                  360.360se                            winget
3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget
```

Using javascript, how would I parse this string to get a result of something like:

```
['app115', 'app225', 'Knotes', 'BPMN-RPA Studio', 'Fishing Funds', '360', '360', '360', '360', '3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition)']
```

Here are some of my ideas that I couldn't get to work:
**step 1**, since the second two columns are not necessary, we can start by replacing 'winget' with blank text `string1.replaceAll("winget", "")` this removes the whole left column because all values in that column are 'winget'.
**step 2**, <s>remove all occurrences of multiple characters that are surrounded by 2 or more spaces on each side. This should get rid of the whole second column because each value has at least two spaces on each side.</s> -- *will not work because if the value in the first column is too long, the value in the second column may only have one space next to it. Check the last row of the original string.*
**last step**, once string now looks something like: `"app115 app225 Knotes BPMN-RPA Studio Fishing Funds..."`, make into an array using `string.split(" ")`
Hope my question makes sense.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Since columns have a fixed size, use `String.prototype.substr` for each line and trim on the right.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what do you mean by "columns have a fixed size"

Comment: In your example the first column is 38 characters long.

Comment: Each field uses the same number of characters, so that the second field always lines up.

Comment: @Barmar but they could have been \t

Comment: Unfortunately, given the last line `3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner` there is no sense of where the column ends unless the column width is fixed with an amount of characters. Given that, why not use a regex ? [/^.{38}/gm](https://regex101.com/r/FWOPGc/1) or with trim [/^.{1,38}(?<!\s)/gm](https://regex101.com/r/iJWhbF/1) This will be deleted if not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me

Assuming any kind of whitespace including tabs between the columns

`\s+\w+\.` is the leading whitespace BEFORE a string with a fullstop

```js
const lines = table.split(/\r?\n/)
const column1 = lines.map(line => line.split(/\s+\w+\./)[0])
console.log(column1)
```

```html
<script>
const table = `app115                                115.115                              winget
app225                                115.115Chrome                        winget
Knotes                                1MHz.Knotes                          winget
BPMN-RPA Studio                       1ic.BPMN-RPAstudio                   winget
Fishing Funds                         1zilc.FishingFunds                   winget
3601                                  360.360Chrome                        winget
3602                                  360.360Chrome.X                      winget
3603                                  360.360CleanMaster                   winget
3604                                  360.360se                            winget
3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget`
</script>
```

If column1 is always 38 chars long, then

```js
const lines = table.split(/\r?\n/)
const column1 = lines.map(line => line.slice(0,38).trim())
console.log(column1)
```

```html
<script>
const table = `app115                                115.115                              winget
app225                                115.115Chrome                        winget
Knotes                                1MHz.Knotes                          winget
BPMN-RPA Studio                       1ic.BPMN-RPAstudio                   winget
Fishing Funds                         1zilc.FishingFunds                   winget
3601                                  360.360Chrome                        winget
3602                                  360.360Chrome.X                      winget
3603                                  360.360CleanMaster                   winget
3604                                  360.360se                            winget
3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget`
</script>
```

Comment: if the column is 38 chars long, you can also do: `table.match(/^.{0,37}\S/gm);`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - I like `/^.{1,38}(?<!\s)/gm` since it has trim without matching it.

Comment: Regex is really a 1 line solution nowadays. No need for split's, temporary's or all that.

Comment: Sure - I am not disputing that. My solution is line based on purpose

Comment: @sln that is the reason I did the bare minimum: for readability's sake. If the table is the size of what OP gave us, there is no reason to get a genius regexpert to craft the unreadable thing you provided. It works beautifully, but OP would NEVER be able to maintain/change this regexp without asking again. I even have a hard time reading it, and would never consider writing it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will extract the first column that is of fixed length ( *38 here* ).
It's a template, can be adapted to work to get any column though.
It also trims leading and trailing whitespace. [(?<=^\s*(?!\s)).{1,38}(?<!\s)(?<=^.{1,38})|^(?=\s{38})](https://regex101.com/r/BzR6eJ/1)
This is a single operation and is a Template that is valid only when using variable
length look behind construct engines like JS and C#.

The regex is no more complex than putting together a password regex.

```
  (?<=               # Alignment using a look behind assertion
    ^ \s*              # Beginning of line, optional ws
    (?! \s )           # Not a ws forward
  )
  .{1,38}            # 1-38 characters width column
  (?<! \s )          # Look behind assertion for trailing ws trim
  (?<= ^ .{1,38} )   # Look behind assertion to fix overall length to 38
| 
  ^                  # Or the entire column is WS
  (?= \s{38} )       # Check with look ahead asserstion
```

```js
column1 = table.match( /(?<=^\s*(?!\s)).{1,38}(?<!\s)(?<=^.{1,38})|^(?=\s{38})/gm )
console.log(column1)
```

```html
<script>
const table = `app115                                115.115                              winget
app225                                115.115Chrome                        winget
   Knotes                             1MHz.Knotes                          winget
BPMN-RPA Studio                       1ic.BPMN-RPAstudio                   winget
Fishing Funds                         1zilc.FishingFunds                   winget
3601                                  360.360Chrome                        winget
                                      1zilc.FishingFunds                   winget
3602                                  360.360Chrome.X                      winget
3603                                  360.360CleanMaster                   winget
3604                                  360.360se                            winget
3CX Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget
    Call Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget
         Flow Designer (.exe edition) 3CX.3CXCallFlowDesigner              winget`
</script>
```

To generalize the above to get *any column*, just the column offset (in characters)
and the column width are needed. These can be plugged into this regex template:
[(?:(?<=^.{N}\s*(?!\s)).{1,W}(?<!\s)(?<=^.{N}.{1,W})|(?<=^.{N})(?=\s{W}))](https://regex101.com/r/ChcObI/1)
Where *N* is the Offset up to the column. *W* is the Width of the column.
In the linked example, *N = 10*, *W = 38*.

```
(?:
  (?<=               # Alignment using a look behind assertion
    ^ .{N} \s*         # Offset to column and leading ws trim
    (?! \s )           # Not a ws forward
  )
  .{1,W}             # 1 - width column characters
  (?<! \s )          # Not a ws behind for trailing ws trim
  (?<=               # Behind col offset and 1 - width, to fix overall length
    ^ .{N} .{1,W}   
  )
|                   # Or the entire column is WS
  (?<= ^ .{N} )      # Alignment behind offset to column
  (?= \s{W} )        # Ahead insure entire column is ws
)
```